# My code is meant to be an accessible website with dynamic sizing. Could you analyze my page structure for any opportunities to optimize it?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

Been learning front-end web development on the side on and off for the past few months. I don't really have any mentors to reach out to to look at my code so I thought I'd see if anyone here was interested in doing a quick code review on my latest HTML/CSS code.

I tried to use semantic tags where possible and I avoided any absolute units. I focused on accessibility with this one. I feel like I overused flexbox What do you guys think?

[Github pages preview:](https://pmevers.github.io/html-css-practice/)

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>HTML/CSS Practice</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <div class="logo-wrapper">
                    <img class="logo-image" src="./images/odin-lined.png">
                    <p class="logo-text">Odin</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <figure class="background">
                <img class="background-image" alt="Peaceful ripples on a lake." src="./images/tom-barret-ripples.jpg">
                <figcaption>
                    <p class="background-image-credits">Photo by
                        <a class="credits"
                            href="https://unsplash.com/@wistomsin?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Tom
                            Barrett</a>
                        on
                        <a class="credits"
                            href="https://unsplash.com/backgrounds?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Unsplash</a>
                    </p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </header>
        <div class="right">
            <h1>This is not a real online service. You should NOT enter any personal information here.</h1>
            <main id="main-content">
                <div class="main-container">
                    <h2>Sign up now!</h2>
                    <form>
                        <ul>
                            <div class="form-wrapper">
                                <li class="label-and-input">
                                    <label for="name">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
                                </li class="label-and-input">
                                <li class="label-and-input">
                                    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="last-name" name="user_last_name">
                                </li>
                                <li class="label-and-input">
                                    <label for="mail">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_name">
                                </li>
                                <li class="label-and-input">
                                    <label for="telf">Phone Number</label>
                                    <input type="number" id="telf" name="user_telf">
                                </li>
                                <li class="label-and-input">
                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="password" name="password">
                                </li>
                                <li class="label-and-input">
                                    <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="confirm-password" name="confirm_password">
                                </li>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                        <button class="create-account" type="submit">Create Account</button>
                    </form>
                    <p class="login-link">Already have an account?
                        <a href="">Log in</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </main>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code:

````
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;

}

.container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* Need new image with better scaling */
    background-image: url("./images/tom-barret-ripples.jpg");
    background-size: 50% 40%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    z-index: +1;
    overflow: visible;
}

header {
    max-width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.logo {
    flex-grow: 0;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 25%;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
}

.logo-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 30%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.596);
    margin-top: auto;
}

.background-image {
    display: none;
}

.logo-text {
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.logo-image {
    max-height: 70%;
}

.background-image-credits {
    flex-grow: 0;
    font-size: .8rem;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1rem;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.credits {
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-top: auto;
}

.right {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    gap: 2rem;
    color: rgb(20, 47, 64);
}

.form-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    grid-gap: 1.2rem;
}

main {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgb(132, 114, 114, 0.401);
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.main-container {
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.label-and-input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(83, 80, 99);
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-style: italic;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 70%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(132, 114, 114, 0.401);
    padding-top: .6em;
    padding-bottom: .6em;
}

.create-account {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 1.2rem;
    background-color: rgb(181, 129, 89);
    border: none;
    padding-top: .6rem;
    padding-bottom: .6rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.create-account:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #3e4636;
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

### The mobile experience

I simulated how it would look on a phone and got this:

[image: narrow window]

You should note a number of things:

- The h1 is cut off
- The left sidebar isn't big enough to show me the name of the site, nor the attribution link. It probably shouldn't be a sidebar on sufficiently small screens (a top bar instead?)

  - The attribution link is over the word "Password" (if you scroll down) so I accidentally went to another page instead of typing in my password
- The page scrolls. It should really fit to the small width of the phone instead.
- The input boxes are all too small. When I design a mobile form, I generally put each input on its own line (at least at narrow widths) so that it maximizes the length of what can be typed before it starts scrolling. This would also fix the fact that (for example) the input for email and phone number are not vertically aligned.

### The experience for low-vision users

- Having the alt text "Peaceful ripples on a lake" [makes sure a screen reader doesn't skip the figure](https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2019/01/21/how-do-you-figure.html). But does a screenreader user care to know what the image portrays? Don't you think this is a [decorative image](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/), which shouldn't be announced? Mozilla recommends you ['[o]nly use role="figure" if you have to'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/figure_role). In addition, `<img class="logo-image" src="./images/odin-lined.png">` seems to be only there for the alt; you even acknowledge this with your CSS: `.background-image {display: none;}`. All things considered, I would remove the `img` and make the figure and its caption into  `div`s.
- Your other alt text is missing. You can use `alt=""` here because [WebAIM recommends using the company name](https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#logos) ("Odin") in the alt text but you already have the company name as adjacent text, so there's no reason to be redundant.
- The button [lacks enough contrast](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=FFFFFF&bcolor=B58159)
- I found that reading the attribution text on a multicolored background was annoying (possibly indicating there's some low-contrast there) so you could have a dark overlay to make it easier to read

### Validation

- [Phone number shouldn't be a "number"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)
- [Password fields shouldn't be "text"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password)
- It shouldn't be possible to submit with [all the fields blank](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required), or with [too few or too many characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/min) of input